# compile error in declaration of a class inheriting from a template class:

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I don't understand what is wrong with the declaration of the derived file. Please help me find the issue with it.
This is the content of my header file:

```
/*
* STLSandbox.h
*
*  Created on: Aug 4, 2012
*      Author: aksinghdce
*/

#ifndef STLSANDBOX_H_
#define STLSANDBOX_H_



namespace amit {

class STLSandbox {
public:
    STLSandbox();
    virtual ~STLSandbox();
};
template<typename T>
class MyCotainer{
public:
    virtual void inserthere(T&) = 0;
    virtual void deletehere(T&) = 0;
    virtual const void printhere(T&) = 0; //promise not to modify anything
};

template<typename T>
class VectorOf: public MyContainer<T>
{
public:
    virtual void inserthere(T&);
    virtual void deletehere(T&);
    virtual const void printhere(T&);
private:
    std::vector<T&> v_data; // vector of references of type T
};

template<typename T>
void VectorOf<T>::inserthere(T& item){
    v_data.push_back(item);
}

template<typename T>
void VectorOf<T>::deletehere(T& item){
    v_data.pop_back(item);
}

template<typename T>
const void VectorOf<T>::printhere(T& item){
    std::vector<T>::iterator i = null;
            for(i=v_data.begin();i<v_data.end();i++)
            {
                std::cout<<*i<<std::endl;
            }
}

}

#endif /* STLSANDBOX_H_ */
```

I am using gcc 4.2.1

The following are the error I am getting:

```
[...]/STLSandbox.h:26: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
[...]/STLSandbox.h:26: error: expected `{' before ‘<’ token
[...]/STLSandbox.h:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
[...]/STLSandbox.h:37: error: ‘template<class T> class amit::VectorOf’ used without template parameters
[...]/STLSandbox.h: In function ‘void amit::inserthere(T&)’:
[...]/STLSandbox.h:38: error: ‘v_data’ was not declared in this scope
[...]/STLSandbox.h: At global scope:
[...]/STLSandbox.h:42: error: ‘template<class T> class amit::VectorOf’ used without template parameters
```

Comment: ignoring other error, main issue is you can't create vector of ref `std::vector<T&> v_data;` , consider vector of `std::reference_wrapper<T>` if you're using C++11

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its just a typo. You have defined the class `MyCotainer` (note the missing n) but are using the correct `MyContainer` later.

Comment: you edited the question, you should have fixed that typo also

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I don't think that's appropriate since it would make the question moot

Comment: I would suggest that the question is valid. At least here would be a reference of these specific error strings for these kind of silly but torturous errors!